# How to create a table with advanced titles (multi layers)

Tags: tables, sectioning, lists, multicolumn

I am trying to create a table that would look something like this but I am struggling with how to put an additional text

What I want to achieve:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
                                    Birth date
Name           Surname        day    Month    Year   
-------------------------------------------------------
Jimmy          Neutron        26      9       1834
Bob             Ross          32      2       1234
-------------------------------------------------------
```

What I have now:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l r r l }
        \toprule
         &  & Date \\ 
        Name & Surname & day &  month & year   \\
        \midrule
        Jimmy & Neutron & 20 & 09 & 1984 \\
        Bob & Ross & 2 & 12 & 1184 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Body segment length measurements}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Add this row `& &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Birth date} \\ ` just after `\toprule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved by @Bernard comment, however, in your code fragment you defined four columns, but you need five. I suggest to change their type as is done in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ r l ccc }
        \toprule
                &           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Date}  \\
        \cmidrule{3-5}
        Name    & Surname   & day   & month & year      \\
        \midrule
        Jimmy   & Neutron   & 20    & 09    & 1984      \\
        Bob     & Ross      & 2     & 12    & 1184 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Body segment length measurements}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]